# Can't access SQL Server remotely that resides on an Azure Windows Server 2019 Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have SQL Server Express installed on an Azure Windows Virtual Machine.
Steps I have taken:

- updated the default port for SQL server in SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- verified sql server is listening on that port (netstat -ano)
- Added a Windows firewall rule to accept inbound traffic on that port (Scope of the rule limits to my static IP address)
- added an inbound rule in Azure to allow access to that default port (Source IP address same as IP in Windows Firewall)
- Verified Remote Connections are enabled in SSMS
- Mixed authentication is enabled.
- Verified user created is able to access the desired databases by logging in locally with Sql Server Management Studio.  This is a sql server user and not a computer account

I am able to telnet and nc to the port.

The name of the SQL Server looks like this when i access it locally on the VM

- localhost\SERVER_NAME or
- hostname\SERVER_NAME

From a remote machine I am attempting to access this database using SSMS.
I have tried:

- mydomain.com\SERVER_NAME  -mydomain.com does resolve to the correct IP address
- mydomain:1234\SERVER_NAME -1234 represents the default port that was set

I have verified the user name and password are correct.  I have also tried turning off the Windows firewall which leads me to believe it might be the inbound rule in Azure but there's really nothing special to that rule, just allows traffic to the sql server port (1234, in this example).
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct connection string in SSMS is
mydomain,1234\SERVER_NAME

comma before port not colon.

Comment: How did you validate the correct format to your connection string? via the link i sent you? If yes, then accept my answer so other people can reference to it. I will update the answer to specify the specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please have a look to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect), if you did not yet, and ensure that you did all the steps required? To highlight a few important steps, please ensure:

1. Set the connectivity to publish
2. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to manually enable the TCP/IP protocol
3. Use the SSMS to connect to your DB and use the following server address for your VM

Hope that it helps.

Comment: *"and use the following server address for your VM"*... What following Address? The bullet points you give here appear to be incomplete.

Comment: unable to find sql server connectivity settings in the Azure settings for this VM

Comment: @Larnu i just highlighted few important steps, i did not include a full list of steps, otherwise it would be a copy of the article i referenced...  and that's not my point.

Comment: @user2370664 did you create your VM using an existing image on the Azure marketplace? So, the settings mentioned in the article are available on images with SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016 (i believe they are available on later versions as well)

Comment: *"otherwise it would be a copy of the article i referenced"* but that is *exactly* what you should be doing @HugoBarona , along with adding you're own points. Otherwise if the link ever becomes dead, your answer isn't helpful to any future readers. You should be citing the relevant parts of the link in your answer, so that it is complete without the link; though the link should be there as a citation and to provide further reading.

Comment: ok @Larnu i got your point. I will update the answer then, after the user2370664 answers my question and we figure out his issue.

Comment: I did not create the VM from the marketplace.  I created a regular Windows Server 2019 virtual machine in Azure then installed SQL Server Express on it.

Comment: In that case, please try to follow these manual steps referenced in [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore). You should be able to configure it manually.

Comment: That link does not seem relative at all